# Create a function with an if statement inside

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I want to write a function such as `f(x)` with an `if` statement and make this function accessible from another file, more or less as if it were a `sin(x)` function. Moreover, I'd like to plot this function for a range of `x` values, but I keep getting an error. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fyd=450/1.15

def f(es):
    if es < 0.002:
        return fyd*es/0.002
    else:
        return fyd;


x=np.arange(0.0000,0.01,0.0001)

plt.plot(x,f(x))
plt.show()
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to `map` your function `f` over the array `x`; you can't call `f(x)` directly, as the function doesn't deal correctly with `<` for an array (rather than a single value).

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with the `if` statement in a function. Did you search for the error message? What did you find, what confused you about how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `es < 0.002`?

Comment: ``np.arange`` returns an array which you then pass to function ``f`` as ``es``. The line ``es < 0.002`` performs comparison between array and float and causes this error. Maybe you were looking to compare specific values like ``es[0] < 0.002``?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it might be related to the `if` statement, because that's where `array.__nonzero__` is called.

Comment: @RedBaron comparison between `numpy.array` and a scalar is legitimate and returns an array of `bool`s. It seems to fail one step later, while trying to figure out the boolean value of an array.

Comment: @bereal Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: @bereal: ah, of course. it *is* the `if` statement. The issue can be reproduced with `bool(x < 0.002)`, because `x < 0.002` produces an `array` with booleans.

Comment: @RedBaron, you are correct. that's what I am doing wrong. at the end of the if statement the function f(es) works whenever I introduce a scalar in place of es. If I introduce an array, then it doesn't work. I should probably start over and think it differently if I want (es) to be an array or a list of numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `es < 0.002` produces an array of booleans; each value in the input array is tested and the outcome of each of those tests informs the output array; `True` if that individual value is smaller than `0.002`, `False` otherwise:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> fyd=450/1.15
>>> x=np.arange(0.0000,0.01,0.0001)
>>> x < 0.002
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

You cannot use that array in an `if` test, because you cannot unambiguously say if this is true or false:

```
>>> bool(x < 0.002)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If you used `a.any()` you get `True` because there is at least one `True` value in the array; `a.all()` would give you `False` because not *all* values are true:

```
>>> (x < 0.002).any()
True
>>> (x < 0.002).all()
False
```

Pick the one that fits your needs, and use that in the `if` statement:

```
def f(es):
    if (es < 0.002).any():  # or .all()
        return fyd*es/0.002
    else:
        return fyd
```